# 'file is not a database' or 'No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.' when creating Database.sqlite in non-default path

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, discord.net

I am an extremely novice C# programmer following a series of video tutorials using Discord.net and sqlite to create a bot for my server to add various commands and automate various tasks.

Everything has gone fine in the tutorial until I reached the sixth installment, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Lf6w7WZvT0. A little after 12:30, the author attempts to use `update-database` in the Package Manager Console to create a database named `Database.sqlite` at a non-default location. However, attempting to create this database the way he has it written results in an error, `SQLite Error 26: 'file is not a database'.`

The tutorial author's solution is to create the database at the default location, manually move it to the preferred location, then edit the code to use the preferred location. To me this seems inelegant and I'd like to figure out how to make the Package Manager Console create the progam in the correct location.

Here is the program as the tutorial author originally writes it

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace MyBot.Resources.Database
{
    public class SqliteDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Stone> Stones { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder Options)
        {
            string DbLocation = string DbLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1",
                @"Data\Database.sqlite");
            Options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + DbLocation);  

        }
    }
}
```

This results in the `file is not a database` error.

He then changes this to

```
            string DbLocation = string DbLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1",
                @"Data\Database.sqlite");
            Options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Database.sqlite"_;
```

This creates a `Database.sqlite` file in the `MyBot` directory, which the author then moves to the `MyBot\Data` directory. He then changes the program to

```
            string DbLocation = string DbLocation = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1",
                @"Data\");
            Options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbLocation}Database.sqlite";
```

And from there the program runs as expected.

I deleted the `Database.sqlite` file and reran the code as it is above to see what happens, and got the message `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.`

Rerunning the various steps leads to the same result each time.

I've attempted to google for the two error messages and haven't found anything useful. I also checked the api page for `DbContextOptionsBuilder` at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder and couldn't find anything that would indicate why it wasn't working.

Any help getting the `Database.sqlite` file to write to `MyBot\Data` would be much appreciated.

Comment: what type of application is this and was it a .netcore app or a .net Framework App, what version of EFCore are you using?  I should have started off with this on my previous attempt answer.  I will update it when you can give me this info.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response!
The type of application is a bot for running various commands on a discord chat server.
It's a .netcore application, version 2.1.0.
It's using EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, EntityFrameworkCore.Design, EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design, and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. Those are all version 2.2.1 except Sqlite.Design which is v1.1.6.
It also uses Discord.Net which is version 1.0.2.
Let me know if there's anything else you need to know!

Comment: console/webapp or is it a dll that is used by Discord?